# God always reports Socket drbunix:///tmp/god.17165.sock already in use by another instance of god

Tags: ruby, deployment, monitoring, god

I am using God for the first time to monitor my resque and resque-sceduler process.I followed the tutorial on [God's home page](http://godrb.com/). According to that if god if there is already a watch added to God by:

```
sudo god -c /path/to/config.god
```

then after editing the watch it can be added to God again using the same command. But it does not allow to add it and reports that sock is already in use, I have to manually kill the process and add the watch again. Am I missing something?

I need to add the watch again after every deployment, that is why I am trying to do this.

Comment: Goddamned polytheists! :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo hehe, well god makes you do everything.. :P, but please answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The page you link to](http://godrb.com/) does not actually support your assertion that you reload watches by using the same command that starts `god`, to wit:

```
sudo god -c /path/to/config.god
```

Instead it says to use:

```
sudo god load path/to/config.god
```

Specifically, the extracted parts of that page are:

---

> **STARTING AND CONTROLLING GOD**
>
> To start the god monitoring process as a daemon simply run the god executable passing in the path to the config file (you need to sudo if you're using events on Linux or want to use the setuid/setgid functionality):
>
> `$ sudo god -c /path/to/config.god`
>
> `: : : : :`
>
> **DYNAMICALLY LOADING CONFIG FILES INTO AN ALREADY RUNNING GOD**
>
> God allows you to load or reload configurations into an already running instance. There are a few things to consider when doing this:
>
> - Existng Watches with the same name as the incoming Watches will be overidden by the new config.
> - All paths must be either absolute or relative to the path from which god was started.
>
> To load a config into a running god, issue the following command:
>
> `$ sudo god load path/to/config.god`

---

If you're relying on the text:

> Ctrl-C out of the foregrounded god instance. Notice that your current simple server will continue to run. Start god again with the same command as before.

then that's only for a *foregrounded* instance of `god`, one run with `-D`. If you CTRL-C that, then `god` will stop (but the servers it started will continue). If you're `god` instance is running in the *background* (no `-D`), you need to use `kill` to stop it in the same manner.

Comment: Lines from the page: "Ctrl-C out of the foregrounded god instance. Notice that your current simple server will continue to run. Start god again with the same command as before. Now instead of starting the simple process, it will notice that one is already running and simply switch to the up state."

Comment: @infantDev, that's only for a _foregrounded_ server, see the update.